# Groovy File Traverse behavior when parsing file

Tags: groovy, file-type

I have a closure working properly on traverse, but another of the same kind is failing. I'm suspecting scope or timing is causing this to fail. The working code sums the size of files in the file system. The code not working is inspecting the content of the file and only prints one match. Running these with Grails 2.3.7

working code:

```
def groovySrcDir = new File('.', 'plugins/')
def countSmallFiles = 0
def postDirVisitor = {
   if (countSmallFiles > 0) {
      println "Found $countSmallFiles files with small filenames in ${it.name}"
   }
   countSmallFiles = 0
}
groovySrcDir.traverse(type: FILES, postDir: postDirVisitor, nameFilter: ~/.*\.groovy$/) {
   if (it.name.size() < 15) {
      countSmallFiles++
   }
}
```

problem code:

```
def datamap = [:]
def printDomainFound = {
   //File currentFile = new File(it.canonicalPath)
   def fileText = it.text
   if(fileText.indexOf("@Table ") > 0){
      //println "Found a Table annotation in ${it.name} "
      datamap.put(it.name, it.name)
   }
}
groovySrcDir.traverse type: FILES, visit: printDomainFound, nameFilter: filterGroovyFiles
datamap.each {
   println it.key
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and worked fine.

Which behaviour are you expecting?

I find a couple of suspicious things:

- If `fileText` begins with `"@Table "` then `indexOf` will return 0 and the condition `if(fileText.indexOf("@Table ") > 0)` will not be satisfied.
- `"@Table "` has a trailing space, then a file containing, for example: `"@Table("`, will not be printed.

You can also check that `filterGroovyFiles` has the appropiate value.

I hope it'll help.

-- EDIT --

Running the code with `def filterGroovyFiles = ~/.*\.groovy$/` and this file tree:

```
plugins
|--sub1
|  |-dum.groovy
|  |-dum2.groovy
dum3.groovy
```

And all three groovy files containing the (but not starting with!!) "@Table " (with trailing space!!). I get the expected output:

```
dum3.groovy
dum.groovy
dum2.groovy
```

(Note both dum.groovy and dum2.groovy from the same folder sub1 are appearing).

I'm using groovy 2.0.5.

Please recheck your files :

- Have the correct extension
- Contain but not at the begining (index==0) the String "@Table "

Comment: The behavior I was seeing was that the first file in a directory which satisfied the regex match was the only line printed and then processing stopped(one line only), even though the print on countSmallFiles printed for every subdirectory. I'm using grails 2.3.7.  I'll try running with an older version of grails to see if I get the same results.

Comment: a little different approach, but working for me:
`def groovySrcDir = new File('.', 'plugins/')
def result = new AntBuilder().fileset( dir:'./plugins/', includes:'**/*.groovy' ) {
  containsregexp expression:'.*@Table.*'
}*.file
result.each(){ f ->
 def fileText = f.text
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(@Table|@NamedQuery).*?(name).*?(=).(\\S+)(\\))");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(fileText);

/*  @NamedQuery not working.  I suspect the naming of string.string is breaking the REGEX  */
 while (m.find()) {
     print "${f.name} \treferences table: " + m.group(4).replace("\"", "");
 }
} `

Comment: I don't understand. If I run the code I get a line for all files that have "@Table ". I'll edit my answer with more details.